# Getting a next week date

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL

```
ID Date

001 2010-08-01
002 2010-08-15
003 2010-08-22
...
....
```

Query

```
select ID, Date from table where date < curdate + 7;
```

The above query is not working, it showing error.

How to get date upto nextweek date, I don't want to mentioned the date, it should calculate the systemdate + 7 days.

For Example

Today is 2010-06-30,

So it should take a value upto 2010-07-06

How to make a query for this condition....?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the `DATE_ADD()` function:

```
... WHERE date < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

using an operator:

```
.... WHERE date < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

[reference on date_add](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

I'm assuming that by `curdate`, you mean the function and not a column name. If it's a column name, change accordingly (although I wouldn't name a column after an existing mySQL function.)

Comment: This is not next week, this is 7 days ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

select ID, Date from table where Date < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)